# API get of multiple contact_sub_type returns no results

Tags: api, issues, contact-types

I have this problem on the Joomla demo site (4.6.0) and my own sites with versions 4.6.8 and 4.7.1.

If I use the API explorer or run test php code, with a query checking for multiple contact_sub_type, I get 0 results:

```
$result = civicrm_api3('Contact', 'get', array(
  'sequential' => 1,
  'return' => "contact_sub_type",
  'contact_sub_type' => array('IN' => array("Student", "Parent")),
));
```

But if I search using the = operator for one contact_sub_type at a time, it returns the expected results:

```
$result = civicrm_api3('Contact', 'get', array(
  'sequential' => 1,
  'return' => "contact_sub_type",
  'contact_sub_type' => "Parent",
));

{"is_error":0,"version":3,"count":1,"id":7,"values":[{"contact_id":"7","contact_sub_type":["Parent"],"contact_is_deleted":"0","id":"7"}]}
```

This happens with subtypes of both Organization and Individual types.

I could work around it by performing multiple api calls and merging the results, but this seems like a bug?

Comment: I just ran into the same thing and I agree, this seems like a bug. Have you submitted a bug to JIRA before? https://issues.civicrm.org/jira/secure/CreateIssue!default.jspa

Comment: I have used JIRA before, but have not submitted a bug report for this issue.  What CiviCRM version are you using?  I haven't tested any releases newer than 4.7.1.

Comment: When getting ready to submit a bug report it's a good idea to test on the demo server with the latest version so you can specify steps to repeat the issue in your bug ticket. e.g. http://dmaster.demo.civicrm.org

Comment: Filed a bug at https://issues.civicrm.org/jira/browse/CRM-18403